# Why doesn't my Xbox 360 connect via HDMI

Tags: xbox-360

I have just set up my brand new, out of the box Xbox 360 to my TV, o connected it to av so I could get the initial settings done, now I connected a HDMI cable to it from my TV and all I am getting is a black screen, I know it's still working cause when impress A the disk tray opens

As a test, I disconnected my PS3 HDMI cable and used that, not changing the HDMI port it is in in the TV, the PS3 was working just moments before so it should work with the 360, however I still get a black screen

Unlike the PS3 where I had to set the display settings to HDMI while on AV there is no setting like that on the 360, the HDMI Settings is grated out while I am on AV

I have tried

1. Disconnecting the AV Cables so its just HDMI, nothing
2. Going into AV, remembering what I need to press to get to The HDMI Setting and looking up where the Recommended settings option is, nothing
3. Changing to one of the many, many other HDMI Cables I have, all nothing
4. Googling what I could do, most posts say that your 360 needs to be fixed, mine is brand new

I don't want to play in AV cause I saw Assassins Creed 3 in AV on my dad's TV and boy is it bloody hard to read anything in that game, when I upgraded his to Component HD (his is first generation so it came with those cable with the AV and Component cables as one with a switch to change between them) and its so much easier, this is why I am insistent that I play using my HDMI Cables

So anyone know why I'm not connecting with my HDMI Cables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [xbox support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/tv-or-monitor-screen-is-blank-while-connected), you may need to try a reset of your display settings:

> - Check the connection for the A/V or HDMI cable on your Xbox console.
> - Check the connection for the A/V or HDMI cable on your television.
> - Try plugging your HDMI cable into a different HDMI port on your television.
> - Reset your display settings. To do this:
>
>   1. Remove any discs from the disc tray.
>   2. Turn off the console.
>   3. Turn on the console.
>
>      **Note** If you are using an Xbox 360 Wireless Controller, turn on the console by using the Guide button on the controller. Make sure that you use the player 1 controller when you do this. The player 1 controller will have the upper-left light illuminated.
>   4. As the console starts, on the controller, press and hold Y while pulling the right trigger. The display settings are reset to the default settings, and then the console automatically restarts.

Since you say you've done the first points, the display setting reset is all that you haven't tried so cold boot the console and hold <kbd>Y</kbd>+<kbd>RT</kbd>.

There is also the possibility that your display is having trouble with the resolution that the 360 is using. It seems to want to default to the highest resolution which not all displays support. The quick test is to try it with a display that you know supports 1080p HDMI in and if it works without changing anything, then that seems to be your problem, but it may still be worth it to try changing the resolution on the 360 anyways:

With an HD AV connector (some connectors have a switch on them for HDTV), ensure that the directions are correct, otherwise you are flying blind. With the current dashboard update:

1. Home button.
2. Settings(all the way to the right).
3. Console Settings(down 3,A).
4. Display(A).
5. HDTV settings(A).
6. Try lower resolutions(up and A selects a lower resolution, but since the menu
   wraps around, I can't be more precise).
7. Set it to the lowest resolution.
8. Power off the console. (if working blind, unnecessary)
9. Switch to the HDMI cable. (if working blind, unnecessary)
10. Power on the console. (if working blind, unnecessary)
11. If that works, go through increasing the resolution setting to find the best resolution that works for your display.

    **Note** I believe it should keep the setting even though you switch cables after setting it, but if I am wrong, you may have to go back and check if it lost your settings, meaning you'll have to do this blind with the HDMI plugged in. You could do this blind to begin with to avoid this extra concern, but I find mistakes are more likely when you can't see.

Make sure to test it thoroughly before writing off a solution. Sometimes Xbox 360 takes a little bit of time as it starts up before it outputs to the screen.

Comment: When I do the Y + RT thing, my screen goes from black to blue (which is the colour of the screen when there is nothing connected) and back to black, still nothing, though in curious what the display setting reset actually does cause since I haven't been able to change any HDMI Settings would it already be on default or forcefully switch back to AV

Comment: To my knowledge, it's supposed to auto-magically detect the HDMI. It is outputting to the HDMI from those results, but the display doesn't understand the signal - either display doesn't support it or 360 signal is altogether bogus. I've updated the answer with more information, but if changing the settings doesn't help, it could be that your new 360 has a defective HDMI out - it happens. Depending where you bought it, they might be able to test it there and help more. Since it's new, at least you have the warranty, etc. so returns, exchanges, and repairs should be simple enough :)

Comment: Apparently [360 does a terrible job at negotiating HDMI connections](http://www.eurogamer.net/forum/thread/215136) because it seems like the HDMI handshake is pretty buggy. Strangely, even working cables for PS3 don't necessarily work for the 360 (which makes no sense with a digial signal) so you may want to try other cables of a different brand if you have them handy. In rarer cases, it is sometimes the TV that messes up the handshake so there may be some magic settings that can help there.

Comment: @skovacs1 - HDMI cables are HDMI cables.  While I agree using a different cable might help, there is no reason a HDMI cable known to be good shouldn't work, and a working PS3 HDMI cable is known to work.

Comment: @Ranhound I know, right? But based on multiple instances of anecdotal evidence that turned up in my research, I felt it turned up often enough to warrant a mention. It really shouldn't matter what with the signal being digital. The protocol should negotiate and error correct signal problems.

Comment: @skovacs1 just wondering, could the HDMI Version of the cable play a factor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Versions, while i'm not 100% sure, the hdmi cable i use on my PS3 is 1.4, the other cables that i brought cheep from ebay (which work with my bluray, av -> hdmi upscaler, wii hdmi adapter, ste top box, ps3 and pc) may also be 1.4, i've yet to try out your revised answer as i am currently at work but while talking to one of the guys at work he said he had a similar problem with his laptop and hdmi and it was because of the version

Comment: @Memor-X That could be the reason as it fits with the anecdotal evidence. Maybe not even the version specifically, but lack of implementation of certain optional feature support for specific cables. Until it's tested, I don't feel confident writing that as the diagnosis, but it seems plausible. If it turns out to be correct, I'll add that to the answer, but first I'll look further into HDMI version/feature support and its relation to this issue.

Comment: @skovacs1 it's finally working, had my friend came over after i tried your edit and failed, the problem is that i was expecting the Xbox 360 to work like a PS3 when it starts up and the internet is connected, the 360 does not respond while it's trying to sign in while with the PS3 you can do what ever and the sign in is a background process, after she worked this out we follows your steps and it it's finally working, i would suggest editing your answer to also accommodate the wait for the 360 to sign in or steps to turn off auto sign in

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last night. Our Xbox 360 worked all day long and when we turned it on after dinner, we received the "no signal" message on the TV. We have a Sony Bravia and the HDMI channels have some settings that can be tweaked. We have been using it for the last year with the HDMI inputs on Auto. This morning I changed the HDMI input on the TV to "on" and the Xbox connected right away. There is some sort of "handshake" that needs to happen between the TV and the Xbox in order for the HDMI port to pick up the signal. If you are having this problem, check your TV HDMI setups.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't do any magic to make your Xbox360 work with HDMI. Just put (only) HDMI cable from the console to TV. It should just work. If it doesn't work, then either your TV can't work with Xbox signal (unlikely), or Xbox HDMI port is not working properly (more likely).

Answer (score -1):

Try this, its what happened to me.

- Turn the xbox and the tv off.
- Plug the hdmi to both the xbox and the TV but first put it into the TV.
- Turn on the TV and wait 3 seconds and then turn on the xbox.
- Wait 3 minutes. If it doesn't work try again 4 more times
- If it still doesn't work then that means your xbox 360 is broken.

Hope this helps.